# Insert Value in Object Aarray (Mongoose)

Tags: node.js, mongoose, model, objectid

I cant update a value in a array object with an ObjectId.
I think it fails when comparing the id of the event Id of the User model that is an ObjectId with the id per parameter that is a string

Model:

```
 tareas: [{
    eventId: {
      type: [Schema.Types.OjectId],
      ref: 'Event'
    },
    tareasDelUsuario: {
      type: []
    }
  }],
```

I tried in controller:

```
await User.findOneAndUpdate(
                    {
                        _id: id,
                        'tareas.eventId': eventId
                    },
                    {
                        $push: {
                            'tareas.$.tareasDelUsuario': tarea
                        }
                    });
```

and:

```
await User.findOneAndUpdate(
                    { _id: id },
                    {
                        "$set": { ['tareas.$[el].tareasDelUsuario']: tarea }
                    },
                    {
                        "arrayFilters": [{ 'el.eventId': eventId}]
                    });
```

Comment: Please show with examples, the problem and what the solution should look like.

Comment: I solved it by defining the eventId (string) as ObjectId (eventId).

using const ObjectId = require ('mongodb')